# Any way to infer the string name value of the defining property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a GraphQL app, and I have a challenge in my GQL type definitions.

```
company: {
  type: OTCompany,
  astNode: fieldDefinitionAST(OTCompany.name, 'company', [authDirective()]),
  description: 'The company the campaign belongs to',
},
createdBy: {
  type: OTUser,
  astNode: fieldDefinitionAST(OTUser.name, 'createdBy', [authDirective()]),
  description: 'The user that created the campaign',
},
```

As you can see, I have a string value that is always exactly the same as the field that it belongs to, in the cases above `company` and `createdBy` . I can't think of any way to get this value automatically without maintaining these fairly fragile string values. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking multiple question in the same question.

Comment: You're right, removed the addon question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [literal types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html):

```
Type Field = "company" | "createdBy";
```

or enums.

Comment: Sure, an enum or type would make it statically typed at least, but what I'm looking for is how to automatically infer it seeing as it's always the same as the property itlself. :)

Comment: @jhm That's only possible with some level of reflection and I don't recommend going down that route. It may appear that the property and the value have something in common, yet a property-name and a value are still very different things. I sense an attempt of doing a [premature abstraction](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureAbstraction). My guess is that you ain't gonna need it.